# How to prevent phpfmt from removing parentheses from "require_once" statements

Tags: moodle, parentheses, require-once

I use phpfmt to format the php files according to PSR1 standard.
Every time I use the Format Document function (Shift + Alt + F) in Visual Studio Code, the parentheses have been removed from the require_once lines.

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/lib/filelib.php');
```

-> `require_once $CFG->dirroot.'/lib/filelib.php';`

This is what I do not want. Because when uploading these files to Moodle, Moodle will throw errors:

```
(#30) "require_once" must be immediately followed by an open parenthesis
```

Problem: How to use the quick format under PSR1 without removing the parentheses of require_once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in settings.json: `"phpfmt.exclude": ["RemoveIncludeParentheses"],`

But its still put a space after `require_once`.